# Google Map - remove markers in URL

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm using a pretty simple Google map:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=53.711517,-1.690869&output=embed
```

Is it possible to remove the markers using the URL? e.g. `&markers=false`

I've searched but cannot find much information about this, if it's even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ll`-parameter instead of `q`

https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=53.711517,-1.690869&output=embed

Answer (score 1):

There you go.
There is an option to save map as is. copy the embed code and extract the link

https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m10!1m8!1m3!1d2361.3786311786757!2d-1.6908690000000002!3d53.711517!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1spt-PT!2s!4v1387471481325

Comment: Thanks, that kind of works, yeah there's no markers but all controls have gone too!

Comment: Controls are in the bottom right. plus this is new googlemap version you can scroll! SCROLL YEAHHH

Comment: Accepted other answer as its closer to what I had simply without the markers but this is correct too and like you say, the scroll is cool